# Java sub-module error creating shaded jar

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I just created a new module in my Dropwizard Project and when I run

```
mvn install
```

I receive the following Exception:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:1.6:shade (default) on project justfortest: Error creating shaded jar: null: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:1.6:shade (default) on project justfortest: Error creating shaded jar: null
```

I did not find anything relevant about it on the internet. Can someone tell me something about it?

Answer (score 0):

*You should not use the shade plugin on your parent project*, but create a separate [aggregator subproject](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB_Enterprise/7.1/html/Getting_Started/files/Develop-Aggregator.html) for this. List all the other subproject you wish to include and add your shading configuration here.